# AsyncApi and RabbitMq

Tags: model, rabbitmq, yaml, amqp, asyncapi

How do I put my RabbitMq exchange to an asyncapi definition?

In the examples I found this ...

```
channels:
  user/signup:
    publish:
      bindings:
        amqp:
          expiration: 100000
          userId: guest
          cc: ['user.logs']
          priority: 10
          deliveryMode: 2
          mandatory: false
          bcc: ['external.audit']
          replyTo: user.signedup
          timestamp: true
          ack: false
          bindingVersion: 0.2.0
```

Is maybe the part of the channel name before the slash meant as exchange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an entire `exchange` property you can use for the [channel binding](https://github.com/asyncapi/bindings/tree/master/amqp#channel-binding-object) for AMQP. The binding you are currently using is the [operation binding](https://github.com/asyncapi/bindings/tree/master/amqp#operation-binding-object).

This means that you can define it as such

```
channels:
  user/signedup:
    publish:
      bindings:
        amqp:
          expiration: 100000
          userId: guest
          cc: ['user.logs']
          priority: 10
          deliveryMode: 2
          mandatory: false
          bcc: ['external.audit']
          replyTo: user.signedup
          timestamp: true
          ack: false
          bindingVersion: 0.2.0
    bindings:
      amqp:
        is: routingKey
        queue:
          name: my-queue-name
          durable: true
          exclusive: true
          autoDelete: false
          vhost: /
        exchange:
          name: myExchange
          type: topic
          durable: true
          autoDelete: false
          vhost: /
        bindingVersion: 0.2.0
```